# How does one pass an argument(s) to a scope in an ActiveAdmin index configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Given an activerecord model called Foo with a scope that requires an argument like this:

```
scope :updated_since, ->(dt) { where( "updated_at >= ?", dt ) }
```

how do I use this in app/admin/foo.rb, i.e. how do I call with the required argument it so that the activeadmin scope button is created?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to create another scope that is the `updated_since` scope for 10 days? If not, clarify what are you trying to do in `scope ->{ "Update in last 10 days", Date.today - 10.days }, :updated_since`

Comment: I want activeadmin to create a scope button that says "Updated in last 10 days" and then also a button that says "Updated in last 30 days".  My coding attempt is probably way off but was included to give the gist of what I'm trying to accomplish, however it can be ignored.  The question I thought spoke for itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a block in the register block like so

```
scope "last 10 days" do |foos|
  foos.updated_since(Date.today - 10.days)
end

scope "last 30 days" do |foos|
  foos.updated_since(Date.today - 30.days)
end
```

Which can be abbreviated like

```
%w(10 30).each do |days_string|
  scope "last #{days_string} days" do |foos|
    foos.updated_since(Date.today - days_string.to_i.days)
  end
end
```

Enjoy ActiveAdmin :)